# Mui Select MenuProps not being applied to MenuItems returned from a method?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to apply MenuProps from a `<Select>` component to the `<MenuItem>`'s in it. These MenuItems are returned from a method. The code looks something like this;

```
const createItems = () => {
    let menuItems: any = [];

        props.options?.map((option) => {
            menuItems.push(<MenuItem key={option.key} value={option.value}>
                {option.value}
            </MenuItem>)
        });
    return menuItems;   
  }


return (
    <FormControl>
      <Select
      MenuProps={{
                  getContentAnchorEl: null,
                  anchorOrigin: {
                      vertical: "bottom",
                      horizontal: "left"
                    }
                }}
      >
      {createItems()}
      </Select>
      </FormControl>
)
```

If I take out the {createItems()} part and substitute it with dummy MenuItem components, then the MenuProps get applied correctly. Any ideas on how to get the MenuProps to apply to MenuItems created in the component? Thanks.

Comment: Works fine for me here: https://codesandbox.io/s/menuprops-with-menuitems-from-function-lhd1i?file=/demo.js. Please create a code sandbox that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there is not much information about the `props.options`. But I will try to answer your question,

I think your menu items are being rendered before the actual `props.options` arrive. So, what you need to do is use useEffect and useState hook.
const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState([]);

```
useEffect(() => {
    const updatedMenuItems: any = props.options?.map((option) => <MenuItem key={option.key} value={option.value}> {option.value} </MenuItem> );
    setMenuItems(updatedMenuItems);
}, [props.options]);

return (
    <FormControl>
       <Select
           MenuProps={{
              getContentAnchorEl: null,
              anchorOrigin: {
                  vertical: "bottom",
                  horizontal: "left"
                }
            }}
       >
            {menuItems}
       </Select>
    </FormControl>
)
```